# Appwidget with collection. Illegal working

Tags: android, android-appwidget

I have `appwidget` with `listview`. Some information we can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18263428/illegal-state-on-click-imageview-with-background-selector)

1) This widget don't worked on 2.x. But user on this devices see this widget at his list and can move it at screen. After he get error. Can I any way to hide this widget on 2.x? Ofcouse, I can set title for this widget as "MyWidget... (3.x-4.x). But I think this is not good.

2) Second issue. On click widget I open my application one `activity` (widgetAct). This is not main activity. widgetAct showed as dialog. All works, but... If I open main activity, next click HOME, not BACK. Now click on widget, opened my widgetAct, but on background I see also main activity.

3) Another case. Open widgetAct. See this activity. Click BACK. Now long press: see last started application. Click on my application (which contain widgetAct) and see this widgetAct. But want see main activity or any another activity my application, but not widgetAct.

I try different cases: add `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY`, `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`, `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`. But nothing help:

```
Intent i = new Intent(ctx, myActivityCls);      i.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, widgetId);
i.setFlags(i.getFlags() | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(viewId, pi);
```

I see, that my widgetAct on open have only `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but... I set some flags to intent and start activity on click widget. Really opened activity have only `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`.

Solutions:
1) Move widget xml provider from xml folder to xml-v11. Now on 2.x devices this widget is hided.

2) Second case: set for widgetAct [taskAffinity](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#aff). But in this case at recent apps I see 2 my application instances, because used 2 stack activities. To fix it add to widgetAct:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}
```

3) On click at widget open widgetAct. I close this instance widgetAct and open another widgetAct, but add next flags: `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY`, `FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS`.